# exact cost of the EC2 instance for 1 hour in Amazon web service foe windows and linux OS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I want to know exact cost of an windows and linux instance. In Amazon pricing list, they show '$0.12 per hour' for windows and '$0.085 per hour' for linux. But in pricing calculator they show ($ 7.16 ) for a month. Which one is correct ? Beacause its a lot of money to spend.

I dont want any links. Can any one tel me exact cost (in $) alone for 1 hour of EC2 instance (Windows & Linux)

Answer (score 3):

The pricing on the Amazon website is accurate per-hour.  Each month has a different number of hours remember.

$0.12 per hour for Windows and $0.085 per hour for Linux, for the Standard instance type.

You certainly do want a link to the Amazon AWS site, because they are the guys who set the prices.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing